# javascript for loop returns a different value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the largest number in a array that is not on its position in the order from small to large.

```
var input=[ 4, 1, 7, 8, 9, 6, 10,11,12,13, 2, 5, 3 ];
function paramid(input){
var max=0
for (var i=0;i<input.length-1;i++){
    for (var j=1;j<input.length;j++){
        if((input[i]>input[j]) && (input[j]>max)) {max=input[j]}          
    }
}
return max
}
```

I expected it to return 6, however it returns 12. Why?

Very sorry that I wasn't clear about the question. Input is a array of number. can only one number from its position to the top until it is in the order from small to large. output array of numbers that moves from first to last. It takes the least amount of moves to rearrange.

Comment: ...............what?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I *think* that you need the inner for loop to start "j" at `i+1` instead of `1`.

Comment: Also I think you don't even need the inner `for` loop, if the psychic powers I'm using to discern the actual problem can be trusted.

Comment: your code is returning 12 because `13 > 12 && 12 > max then max = 12`

Comment: Also no need for `input.length-1` if you use `i<`

Comment: @1.44mb actually I think that's right; it's trying to compare pairs of numbers, so the last pair is when `i` is `length - 2` and `j` is `length - 1`.

Comment: Yes, it never hits the last number.

Comment: are you trying to find the max value in the array ?

Comment: @ Pointy Thank you! starts with j ar i+1 does solve the problem. But why? 12 comes before 13, I don't understand "13 > 12 && 12 > max then max = 12"

Comment: My best guess is that OP wants to ignore 10-13 because they are in sequence, and 7-9 because they are in sequence.  The next highest element in the array after ignoring those ones is 6, does that sound right?

Comment: Very sorry that I wasn't clear about the question. Input is a array of  number. can only one number from its position to the top until it is in the order from small to large. output array of numbers that moves from first to last. It takes the least amount of moves to rearrange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong, You don't need to use 2 for loops for this process,
it can be done with single for loop

```
for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    if(input[i] > input[i + 1] && input[i + 1] > max) { max = input[i + 1] }
}
```

Comment: No, on the last iteration `i` will be `length-2`.

Comment: @Jedi Dula Thank you! Two for loops are unnecessary, this way is much better. Could you explain why 2 for loop would return 12 so I can avoid the same mistake in the future?

Comment: Yes, you're correct it's just a mistake. I'll fix it. Thank you very much.

Comment: O.K. It's very simple to understand why your code return 12, just get some paper and write down first 3 iterations on it. You'll realize 13 is the largest value in input array and after that 12 is the maximum value that greater than 13.

Comment: I got it, it will compare the first number to every other numbers, instead of comparing two nearest numbers in a group. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

your input is

```
[4, 1, 7, 8, 9, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 2, 5, 3]
```

The sorted values are

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

13 appears to be the largest item that is not in its place.

6, on the other hand, is the largest item that **is** at the same place as in the sorted array.

I would do so:

- Sort the array
- Looping on the indices of the array, starting from the last position
- Find if `input[i] == input[j]`. If so, return that

Implementation:

```
var input = [4, 1, 7, 8, 9, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 2, 5, 3];
var sorted = input.slice(0);
sorted.sort();
for (var i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (input[i] == sorted[i]) {
        return input[i]
    }
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your question correctly this is what you are looking for.

```
for(var i=1;i<input.length;i++){
   if((input[i]<input[i-1]) && (input[i]>max)) {max=input[i]}
}
```

Comment: That should be `i<input.length`, otherwise you won't consider the last element in the array.

Comment: umm javascript is 0 indexed, so the last element in the array is at position [lenght -1]  I don't consider the first element in the array, because what i think he wants is the largest unsorted number, and the first element of the array will always appear sorted

Comment: Your loop will run until `i = length-2`, so on the final iteration you will compare the second to last element to the third to last element.

Comment: you are correct i appologize, i thought i had <= in there

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one loop. Just add a `count` variable and test the element's value against it.

```
function paramid(input) {
  var max = 0;
  var count = 1;
  for (var i = 0, l = input.length; i < l; i++) {
    var el = input[i];
    if (el > max && el !== input.indexOf(el) && el === count) {
      max = el;
    }
    count++;
  }
  return max;
}

console.log(paramid(input)) // 6
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/5Tm3D/)